# .. the present I made for you LAST DAY

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, time-words

Are the following sentences grammatical?:

- I went to the cimema last day.
- I finished my reading my book last hour.

The thing that is worrying me is the use of the phrases *last hour* and *last day*. Is this grammatical English?

Comment: The person probably wanted to say "*The other day*" In Italian "scorso" means "last" so the direct translation of *lo scorso giorno" would be *(the) last day* Even Google translator gives this solution https://www.google.co.uk/#q=lo+scorso+giorno+in+inglese

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I agree, that seems very likely.

Comment: Good question. I wonder its answer

Answer (score 2):

Last day is not idiomatic.  Use 'yesterday' instead.

> I hope he gave you the present I made for you yesterday.

'Last hour' as you've written it can be used in a few special situations (like a news broadcast), but it's not an everyday expression.  Normally we'd use *the* last hour, along with an appropriate preposition.

> I hope you looked after my son while I was gone for the last hour.
>
> I was at the doctor's office for the last 4 hours, so I haven't seen the news.
>
> After the last hour of studying, my brain is fried.

Comment: I agree it's nor idiomatic. Is it grammatical?

Comment: If you are using 'last day' as a way to be parallel to 'last week' or 'last month' or 'last year', then yes, I suppose you can call it grammatical.  But what's the point?  Nobody would ever use it.

Comment: I don't think it *is* grammatical! (which is what I was hoping you'd put in your post ;)) Here's a +1 anyway.

Comment: _I finished my reading my book **an hour ago**_ is probably how I'd say it more often than not.

Answer (score 1):

If the time expressions "last day" and "last hour" form a prepositional phrase they become idiomatic and ‘grammatical’.

- I went to the cinema **on the** last day [of my vacation]
- I finished <del>my</del> reading my book **within / at the** last hour

And in the title ...

- I hope he gave you the present I made **last** <del>day</del> **night** for you.

  Weirdly, we can say *last night* and the sentence is perfectly grammatical, but we can't send someone a gift we made ***last day***, ***this day*** or ***next day***. The expression *last night* refers to the previous evening. When we want to refer to the previous day i.e. the OP's ‘Last day’,  in English we call it ***yesterday***, ‘this day’ is called ***today*** while ‘next day’ is called ***tomorrow***.

However, ‘day’ is used in prepositional phrases, or with a determiner because it is a **noun**, while ‘last’ and ‘next’ are  adjectives.

- *I made him a present ***on the*** *last* ***day*** of our honeymoon*
- ***The*** *next* ***day*** I bought a one-way ticket to Hong Kong.
- How kind of you to be with me ***on this day.*** (*‘this’* is a determiner)
- ***On the*** *last* ***day*** of Christmas, my friend sent to me a cosy plaid*.

Comment: Nice post. Might I offer the observation that *last day* and *last hour* can usually only occur with an determiner regardless of whether they're in a preposition phrase :-)

Comment: @Araucaria I've updated the answer. I *think* I have explained why *last day* in the examples is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

"Last day" by itself is not really grammatical or idiomatic.  It's *possible* someone might use it in a sentence ... but if you want to say "the previous day" there is the perfectly good word "yesterday" which works.

It is possible to say various phrases with (or related to) "last day", however:

> This is the last day to purchase your special one-time-only upgrade!
>
> I went to school on the last day of class, but all of the other students [played hooky](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+hooky).
>
> The last few days have been really difficult for me.  What's with all the famous people dying?